# SSRS report not creating sometime

Tags: reporting-services, console-application, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report and it is generating from 4 dataset.

This report sending to client by email from console application in every 1 hour.

**Issue** :
Report working completely as expected but sometime its throw error as below.
Please let me know if anybody have solution.

> at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReportSoapProxy.OnSoapException(SoapException e)
>
> at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod)
>
> at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.Render(String Format, String DeviceInfo, PageCountMode PaginationMode, String& Extension, String& MimeType, String& Encoding, Warning[]& Warnings, String[]& StreamIds)
>
> at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
>
> at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Report.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
>
> at ABC.Program.GenerateExcelAndMail() in d:\XYX\XYZ\Program.cs:line 4875An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)The execution failed for the shared data set 'dsXYZDataset'. (rsDataSetExecutionError)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the root of your problem:

> The execution failed for the shared data set 'dsXYZDataset'

Because the dataset failed your report could not finish running.  Basically you need to dig into the `'dsXYZDataset'` to determine why it only runs intermittently.  Solve that and your report should run consistently.